# Can Flash/AS3 load external images regardless of Content-Type?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

> Disclaimer: I'm not a flash developer
>   but I'm trying to solve a flash issue.
>   Please don't assume I'm intimately
>   familiar with AS or Flash, because I'm
>   not.

The dilemma I currently have is that I'm hosting a resource that is `application/octet-stream`. In my Actionscript code, I'm using some library that ( from what I can recall ) does `new Image` and loads a resource into that object which was created.

There is a method, `loadImage(url)` which accepts a url and that's where you feed it the path to the image.

I do not have access to the `loadImage` source code, so I don't know exactly what it does, but the working one loads the image fine because the `Content-Type` is `image/jpeg`. The non-working one ( this one I'm trying to fix ) doesn't because of the different `Content-Type`.

I'm wondering if someone can tell me if I can make the flash basically parse the URI as if it were `image/jpeg`, regardless of the Content-Type?

> I do not have access to the source
>   code at the moment, but I'm just
>   throwing this out there to get input
>
> If need be, I'll try and get some source code tomorrow

**EDIT:** Ok, I have access to the source now. Here's the part that loads the image:

```
postcardImage = new Image();
postcardImage.loadImage(imagePath);
```

I assume that `Image` the constructor is native to flash/AS, but I haven't been able to google the `loadImage` method so it must be custom, right?

Or could the Image constructor itself be custom? An extended version of the original `Image` with `loadImage` method and such?

<strike>Anyways, does anyone know how I can view the source code of `loadImage`?</strike>

**EDIT #2**: I did an `ack-grep` and found the source code for the `loadImage` method defined in a library:

```
public class Image extends Sprite {

    private var _source:String;
    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var _bmapData:BitmapData;
    private var _loadedBytes:Number;
    private var _totalBytes:Number;

    public function Image() {
        trace('IMAGE');
    }

    public function loadImage(s:String):void {
        _source = s;
        _loader = new Loader();
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoading);
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        _loader.load(new URLRequest(_source));

        function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
            _loadedBytes = e.target.bytesLoaded;
            dispatchEvent(new ProgressEvent(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS));
            if(!_totalBytes) {
                setTotalBytes(e.target.bytesTotal);
            }
        }

        function onLoading(e:Event):void {
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoading);
        }

        function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            _bmapData = e.target.content.bitmapData;
            addChild(e.target.content);
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        }
    }

    public function getBmapData():BitmapData {
        return _bmapData;
    }

    public function duplicate():Image {
        var dup:Image = new Image();
        dup.addChild(new Bitmap(_bmapData.clone()));
        return dup;
    }

    public function getLoadedBytes():Number {
        return _loadedBytes;
    }

    private function setTotalBytes(n:Number):void {
        _totalBytes = n;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("TOTALBYTES_SET"));
    }

    public function getTotalBytes():Number {
        return _totalBytes;
    }

}
```

Can anyone offer advice as to how I can do the `loadBytes` on this? I was thinking of defining a custom method, `loadResource` or something which can load regardless of Content-Type... or just create an optional parameter in the current `load` method and inside, branch out based on what was passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing with ByteArray methods of late and this sounded fun. I've amended your Image class with a method for passing the URL of the octet-stream. Let me know how it works out!

note: I'm not setting the _loadedBytes and _totalBytes properties, but am drawing the loaded image to enable the public 'getBmapData' method.

```
package {
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.net.URLStream;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Image extends Sprite {

    private var _source : String;
    private var _loader : Loader;
    private var _bmapData : BitmapData;
    private var _loadedBytes : Number;
    private var _totalBytes : Number;
    private var _stream : URLStream;
    private var _bytes:ByteArray;

    public function Image() {
        trace('IMAGE');
    }

    public function loadImage(s : String) : void {
        _source = s;
        _loader = new Loader();
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoading);
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        _loader.load(new URLRequest(_source));

        function onProgress(e : ProgressEvent) : void {
            _loadedBytes = e.target.bytesLoaded;
            dispatchEvent(new ProgressEvent(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS));
            if(!_totalBytes) {
                setTotalBytes(e.target.bytesTotal);
            }
        }

        function onLoading(e : Event) : void {
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoading);
        }

        function onLoaded(e : Event) : void {
            _bmapData = e.target.content.bitmapData;
            addChild(e.target.content);
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        }
    }



    // ByteArray methods
    // adapted from Ted Patrick's 
    // http://ted.onflash.org/2007/12/progressive-image-loading-with.php

    public function loadBytes( s:String = "" ):void {

        // FOR EASY TESTING ONLY:
        if( s == "" ) s = "http://onflex.org/flexapps/applications/ProgressiveImageLoading/jpg.jpg";        

        // create URLStream with listeners
        _stream = new URLStream();
        _stream.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS , streamProgress );

        // Not firing, so lets not use it...
        //_stream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , streamComplete );


        // create Loader for later
        _loader = new Loader();

        // create new ByteArray instance
        _bytes = new ByteArray();

        // go ahead and add it to the display list
        addChild( _loader );

        // start the show!
        _stream.load( new URLRequest(s) );

    }

    private function streamProgress(p : ProgressEvent) : void {

        trace("PROGRESS: ",  p.bytesLoaded, "of", p.bytesTotal );

        if( _stream.connected ) _stream.readBytes(_bytes, _bytes.length );

        if( _bytes.length == p.bytesTotal ) {

            // get rid of the event listeners to avoid re-firing 
            _stream.removeEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS , streamProgress ); 

            streamComplete();   
        }
    }

    private function streamComplete() : void {
        _loader.loadBytes( _bytes );
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, makeBitmapData );
    }

    private function makeBitmapData( e:Event ):void{

        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.INIT, makeBitmapData );

        // set the bitmapData for the other public methods
        _bmapData = new BitmapData(_loader.width, _loader.height );
        _bmapData.draw( this );
    }

    //-----




    public function getBmapData() : BitmapData {
        return _bmapData;
    }

    public function duplicate() : Image {
        var dup : Image = new Image();
        dup.addChild(new Bitmap(_bmapData.clone()));
        return dup;
    }

    public function getLoadedBytes() : Number {
        return _loadedBytes;
    }

    private function setTotalBytes(n : Number) : void {
        _totalBytes = n;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("TOTALBYTES_SET"));
    }

    public function getTotalBytes() : Number {
        return _totalBytes;
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: I put some `console.log`s inside of your method and it seems that `streamProgress` is happening ( I made it console.log with a loop counter 5 times ) but it never actually completes. Any idea how I can get around the fact that it never completes? PS - I'm testing in Chrome if that has any relevance.

Comment: Also, the resource has a `Content-Length` if that has any factor? Maybe I could do a # of bytes check and if its equal to the `Content-Length` of the HTTP headers then manually invoke the Event.COMPLETE callback?

Comment: My instinct is that it's not completing because it's a true stream, and not just an image as I'm using in my example. Your second comment is exactly what I'd try, could just call 'streamComplete(null)' when you've got the amount of bytes you're expecting.  I looked for a true octet-stream to try but didn't come up with one quickly. feel free to write me: n at nickhubben dot com.

Comment: Sorry, how would you do the byte length checking inside of the stream progress callback? Apparently I can't do `_bytes.length` since that stays at 0 until its populated and/or the complete callback is done... so I have to use another reference to check the bytes length?

Comment: okee doke. I just edited the file that's above so it's adding bytes to the ByteArray in the ProgressEvent handler. It's also checking the ByteArray's length against the stream that's coming in. It didn't like me trying to access the width/height of the loader right after calling 'loadBytes' so I'm using a Complete handler on the loader.

Comment: This method would also allow you to plug in the _loadedBytes & _totalBytes if you really wanted to.. but a different method for monitoring that stuff might make sense depending on the purpose.

Comment: Ok. It seems that `streamComplete` now gets invoked, but for whatever reason in my file the callback for the image loaded never gets invoked.  `postcardImage.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageComplete);`. Maybe I should pass `onImageComplete` in a custom event, so it gets called internally and I get rid of the `addEventListener`? Or perhaps there's some trickery that we need to do to make the image send a `COMPLETE` status to invoke it.

Comment: Yeah - that'll have to be added manually. I hadn't noticed that the existing `loadImage` method eventually dispatches an `Event.COMPLETE`. Add `dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));` as the last line in `streamComplete` or as the last line of `makeBitmapData` if you need to access the bitmapData right away.

Comment: Like so? http://pastie.org/private/h463eu7cbx1vnhtxzq8xyg For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to invoke the callback after that.. weird.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Not sure what may be preventing the callback... I have a test FLA with just this code and it's working well: `var img:Image = new Image();
img.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgComplete );
addChild( img );
img.loadBytes();
function imgComplete(e:Event):void{
 trace("imgComplete");
}`

Comment: What's the relevance of `addChild(img)`? You already took care of that in your code, right?

Comment: just adding it to my stage so I can see it.  the loader is a child of the Image, which is a child of the stage.

Comment: Do you think perhaps because the code is separated out into 2 files there could be some Event collision, maybe having to do with namespaces or something? ( that sounds confusing... ). I have the `new Image` in an `.fla` and `loadBytes` is defined in an external `.as` file. Also, does your snippet have an explicitly thrown Event for EVENT.COMPLETE, which could better replicate the issue?

Comment: Not positive what you're asking, but I've uploaded my FLA/AS in hopes it will be more clear: [link](http://nickhubben.com/labs/ImageTest.zip)

Comment: That may have something to do with the Security sandbox and converting it to bitmapData.  if you don't actually need the access to the bitmapData, don't call 'makeBitmapData'. It's a whole topic unto itself.

Comment: I spoke too soon because I used the wrong swf.. I tried your way and it didn't seem to work with a local url. I also tried the onflex.org jpg.jpg and it didn't work either... in that EVENT.COMPLETE never gets invoked. I couldn't open your fla because I have CS4. Thanks for all your help though, I'll keep brainstorming.

Comment: If you still care to look, here's a part of the source of my `.fla`: http://pastie.org/private/vmwp4sw8urupdx91qny4w . I tried moving the addEventListener above the loadBytes method just incase that had bearing but apparently not. It never gets to the "inside of onImageComplete" `console.log`

Comment: A dozen or so `console.log`s later, actually it DOES get to `onImageComplete` but it fails after the first if/else branch which is why the second `console.log` never happens.

Comment: Thanks for all your work and appreciate taking the time to comment. I created a new question for the separate resizing issue.

Comment: My pleasure - i had to go a baseball game yesterday, and will be gone today too... You're FLA snippet is very close, with just a few tweaks. Check out this zip, CS4 friendly, with some comments. Also make sure that in your Image.as, it doesn't dispatch the complete event until after the bitmapdata is created. [link](http://nickhubben.com/labs/ImageTest2.zip)

Comment: Hope you had fun @ the game. Actually I moved the `dispatchEvent` to the end of the `makeBitmapData` yesterday after realizing it wasnt firing at the right time. I noticed your new code has 'Event.COMPLETE' on the removeEventListener on `makeBitmapData` and the old one has `Event.INIT`.. I'll try updating that and hopefully that should do it. If not I'll keep comparing the code.

Comment: cool - it had a lot more to do with the way you were targeting things in the FLA's complete handler. trying to get bitmapdata from Loader, etc. Cheers-

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer: Yes.**

I would assume that the code is using a [`Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) object behind the scenes to do the actual image loading/retrieval (this is the standard way of doing such things). Loader objects support PNG, JPEG, and GIF (first frame only) formats.

Now, I'm not sure if Loaders use the content type of the response to guess the image format (I would guess not, but I could be wrong). I do know that Loaders have a `loadBytes()` method which loads an image directly from its raw bytes -- the format sniffing *only* uses the image's actual data in that case, as there is no HTTP request directly involved. So, if it's really the content type that's the culprit, you could load the image separately as raw data, then get an image object from that raw data using `loadBytes()`, bypassing the issue entirely.

We'd have to see the code to really know what's going on, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found the source and pasted it in my question. Any advice you have regarding modifying it would be great.

Comment: By the way, here's my attempt at doing it: http://pastie.org/private/yvuir4clnpdtolfb0yy65a

Comment: @meder: Coming up :-) `Image` is totally custom, by the way -- there's no `Image` class in Flash (just `Sprite`, `Bitmap`, etc.)

Comment: @meder: Your attempt looks good. Is there anything not working?

Comment: I think the complete event handler never gets invoked because its a stream. I am trying out NHubben's code atm.

Comment: I think the same thing is happening with NHubben's code - I don't think the complete callback is ever fired because its a stream? I added some theories in a comment to his answer.